# Swift: Remote Command Center not show in lockScreen

Tags: ios, swift, mpremotecommandcenter

Iam trying to show command center in lock screen and not woking for me,
i see the code from this tutorial, and write the same code but also not working 
https://github.com/lukagabric/LGAudioPlayerLockScreen

this is the code

```
  var nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: currentPlaybackItem.trackName,
                          MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: currentPlaybackItem.albumName,
                          MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: currentPlaybackItem.artistName,
                          MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: audioPlayer.duration,
                          MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: NSNumber(value: 1.0 as Float)] as [String : Any]

    if let image = UIImage(named: currentPlaybackItem.albumImageName) {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
    }
    self.nowPlayingInfoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

Any one can help

Comment: Does the image exist? Is the `if let` block called? Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes image is exist and run code in block `if let`

Comment: Did you update the Info.plist with  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
  <string>audio</string>
 </array>

Comment: yes i added background mode "audio"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,
I found the solution, my last code in set category

```
self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback , mode: .default , options: .mixWithOthers )
```

and the solution is

```
self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback , mode: .default , options: .init(rawValue: 0) )
```

Comment: Tip: If you want to say no options, use `options: []` (your solution works in this case, but should a enum value 0 ever exist, you'll use that value instead of none)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed when trying to update now playing info dictionary you have to fill key with data even empty string.

are you sure `trackName`, `albumName`, `artistName` are not nil ?

[ModernAVPlayer](https://github.com/noreasonprojects/ModernAVPlayer/) has a good example: check this "NowPlaying" [code](https://github.com/noreasonprojects/ModernAVPlayer/blob/develop/Sources/Core/Services/NowPlayingService.swift)